# Using awk to find a line (with regex) then extract word between parantheses

Tags: regex, awk, sh

So I have a text file containing a line with the form:

```
#===== In WORD.BLAH.ETC.WORD.STRING(STUFF) =======
```

I want `STUFF`, and I want to store it in a variable.

So far, I can correctly get the line using `awk '/STRING\(/ { print $0 }' $f`, but I'm not sure how to extract `STUFF`. How is it done? I do not have GNU AWK.

Answer (score 2):

awk to the rescue

```
awk '/STRING/{match($0, "\\\((.*)\\\)", a); print a[1];}'
```

or

```
awk '/STRING/{match($0, /\((.*)\)/, a); print a[1];}'
```

Comment: +1. Requires GNU awk. Can also use the result of the match function as the condition: `awk 'match($0, /STRING\((.*)\)/, a) {print a[1]}'`

Answer (score 1):

The robust way to do this is:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/STRING\(([^)]*)\)/,a) { print a[1] }' file
STUFF
```

That will always only print what's between the parens after STRING, even if there's other parens before or after it on the input line, e.g.:

```
$ cat file
abc(def) STRING(STUFF) ghi(klm)

$ awk '/STRING/{match($0, /\((.*)\)/, a); print a[1];}' file
def) STRING(STUFF) ghi(klm

$ awk 'match($0, /STRING\((.*)\)/, a) {print a[1]}' file
STUFF) ghi(klm

$ awk -F'[.()]' '$2 == "STRING" {print $3}' file
$

$ awk 'match($0,/STRING\(([^)]*)\)/,a) { print a[1] }' file
STUFF
```

The above uses GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match(), with other awks use match()+substr().